# How can I re-enable a JQuery script after a failed validation in a primefaces page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Ok here's the deal... I have a primefaces page, and I'm modifying the `style-class` of some components using a JQuery Script. The problem is that, after a failed validation of some fields, the script stops modifying the `style-class` so the style fails for some components. I'm trying to refresh the page using `update="@form"` on the submit button, but it won't work as the validation is ajax level. Refreshing the page manually works but is not desirable, and won't keep nor the error messages neither the field values that were validated without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what your script is doing but most likely it's working on DOM-Elements which are changed or replaced by an AJAX-call. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        $(this).add('class', 'changed');
    });
});
```

This script registers an event on all input-fields it's finding after the DOM is ready. If an AJAX-call adds a new input field or rerenders one of the input-elements you don't have automatically  registered events on them.

You need to register the events after the AJAX-call again via e.g. `oncomplete="registerEvents();"` where `registerEvents` does the same things you did in your `$(document).ready` function.

Beware of registering events multiple times on the same element.